# Programmatically rotate a pie chart to fix the labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, charts

**Part 1**

I'm looking at a way to automatically rotate (with VBA) a pie chart depending on the data. The data is changed dynamically depending on the month selected. Here is an example of the kind of result I can get:

[image: Pie Chart]

As you can see, the labels, even with the built-in auto-adjust (*best fit*) in Excel, are not looking good. This is because there isn't much space under the chart to put the labels. Actually, since it's a circle in a square, there will always be more space in the corners. Here is how it looks with a 30­° rotation applied manually to the chart, still with *best fit* labels:

[image: Pie Chart]

If you are like me, you will find the second pie chart looking better than the first one.

Now, this is easy, all I had to do to fix my problem was to add a 30° rotation to the chart, but the chart data is loaded dynamically, sometimes I will need 30°, other times it's going to be 270°. The problem only occurs when there are multiple small slices like in the example above.

Is there a way, programmatically, depending on the data, to find where Excel is going to put the small slices in the 360° pie chart and then apply the appropriate rotation when there are 3 consecutive small slices (3 or more slices with a total of less than 10%)?

It looks complicated to do, and I don't understand why Excel doesn't do it automatically, but there must be a way.

---

**Part 2**

Programmatically solve this kind of problem:

[image: Pie Chart 2]

I had to move the labels manually to get something good looking:

[image: Pie Chart 2]

Here's some piece of code to move the labels to avoid contact between each other. I could probably make it work for the situation #2 but it's still pretty complicated. It detects collisions between the labels by looping recursively and moving the labels from each other by a couple of pixels until it's not in collision anymore. But even by looking at which side is in collision with another label, moving it to the opposite side could lead to a worse result. And if there are 4-5 labels in the same zone, the recursive function takes forever to run with some random results. I don't want to put 100 hours of work to develop a better algorithm if there's a better or already existing solution.

```
Sub MoveLabels(chartID As Integer)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ch As Chart
    Dim sers As SeriesCollection
    Dim ser As Series
    Dim i As Long, pt As Long
    Dim dLabels() As DataLabel

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Set ch = sh.ChartObjects("Chart " & chartID).Chart

    Set sers = ch.SeriesCollection
    sers(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionBestFit

    ReDim dLabels(1 To sers(1).Points.Count)
    For i = 1 To sers(1).Points.Count
        Set dLabels(i) = sers(1).Points(i).DataLabel
    Next
    AdjustLabels dLabels
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Sub AdjustLabels(ByRef v() As DataLabel)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ptMove As Integer

    'A label will be moved recursively by that many pixel until it avoids contact
    'More pixels is faster, less pixels is more accurate
    ptMove = 10 

    For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v) - 1
    For j = LBound(v) + 1 To UBound(v)
        If v(i).Left <= v(j).Left Then
            If v(i).Top <= v(j).Top Then
                If (v(j).Top - v(i).Top) < v(i).Height And (v(j).Left - v(i).Left) < v(i).Width And v(j).Text <> v(i).Text And v(j).Text <> "" And v(i).Text <> "" Then
                    v(i).Left = v(i).Left - ptMove
                    v(j).Left = v(j).Left + ptMove
                    AdjustLabels v
                End If
            Else
                If (v(i).Top - v(j).Top) < v(j).Height And (v(j).Left - v(i).Left) < v(i).Width And v(j).Text <> v(i).Text And v(j).Text <> "" And v(i).Text <> "" Then
                    v(i).Left = v(i).Left - ptMove
                    v(j).Left = v(j).Left + ptMove
                    AdjustLabels v
                End If
            End If
        Else
            If v(i).Top <= v(j).Top Then
                If (v(j).Top - v(i).Top) < v(i).Height And (v(i).Left - v(j).Left) < v(j).Width And v(j).Text <> v(i).Text And v(j).Text <> "" And v(i).Text <> "" Then
                    v(i).Left = v(i).Left + ptMove
                    v(j).Left = v(j).Left - ptMove
                    AdjustLabels v
                End If
            Else
                If (v(i).Top - v(j).Top) < v(j).Height And (v(i).Left - v(j).Left) < v(j).Width And v(j).Text <> v(i).Text And v(j).Text <> "" And v(i).Text <> "" Then
                    v(i).Left = v(i).Left + ptMove
                    v(j).Left = v(j).Left - ptMove
                    AdjustLabels v
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next j, i
End Sub
```

Comment: One solution to both my problems would be doing a *pie of pie chart*, but that would also take a lot more room (width) and I want to avoid any 0% pie chart too (so I'd need to programmatically detect whether I want to use a pie chart or a pie of pie chart, but then there's still the width problem since I have lots of other charts in my sheet).

Comment: I'm not of much use with charts, but I'd have to believe there's an add-in or code out there somewhere to fix this problem, that has to be incredibly common. [Here's](http://www.mrexcel.com/tip159.shtml) a suggestion of making the smaller portions into a bar chart, but that seems counter intuitive. Another thing to note is that you have this tagged with excel 2010 where labels behave more rigidly than in excel 2013.

Comment: @Raystafarian This is Excel 2010 and since I'm in a business environment, I don't have much choice here. I'm probably stuck with it for a couple years (we were using Office 2003 a couple of months ago, so it's still a huge improvement). About the *bar of pie chart* suggestion, it's the same thing as a *pie of pie chart* as I previously described in my comment. I looked at that MrExcel.com webpage before posting, after a quick Google search but it wasn't of any help. I would probably be OK to use an addon if it can solve my problems properly.

Comment: And you have your labels set to "best fit" already?

Comment: Yes, I edited "auto-adjusted" to "best fit" in my post (my Excel is in French). Programmatically it's set to *xlLabelPositionBestFit*. I'd say Excel does a great job about 80% of the time.

Comment: Can you use a different chart form (since there are many documented reasons not to use a pie chart)?  Bar charts, laid out horizontally just like the labels are, do very well without much manipulation (or any VBA).

Comment: @dav Bar chart is pretty ugly since we want to compare what the employee has been doing during his time. There are about 25 different categories with each employees usually working in 5-6 different things each months. If we go bar chart, we need to remove all the 0s of the chart dynamically (it changes depending on which employee/month is selected) and the 0-5% bars will be hard to differenciate from each others when there is a 90% segment for example.

Comment: @dav I would also be interested to hear the documented reasons not to use a pie chart, since I've been reading a lot about it and I disagree with all I've read so far for the specific situation I want to show in my chart. Maybe I'm biased, but the decisions to go with a specific chart came from the direction after looking at each charts offered by Excel and trying to find which one is the most representative (they are not specifically IT, and we use bar, area and line charts for other appropriate stuff already).

Comment: Really considering a pie of pie chart right now with VBA to remove the mini-pie when it's empty (adding some width to the next chart to stop the blank gap).

Comment: Here are some resources for you from [Few](http://www.businessinsider.com/pie-charts-are-the-worst-2013-6), [Cole](http://www.storytellingwithdata.com/blog/2011/07/death-to-pie-charts), and [Peltier](http://peltiertech.com/tag/pie-chart/). Oh, and [Gilligan](http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2009/12/02/how-succinctly-can-i-explain-why-pie-charts-are-evil/) thinks they're just plain evil.

Comment: @dav Few's article explains that pie charts can actually be useful. We have 40 employees. For more than 2/3 of them, there would be less than 3 bars in the chart: something like 90%/5%/5%. Pie charts are better at doing that as shown in that article. I want to manage the other 1/3 of the employees, but I still need to be consistent. If I switch to a bar chart, it's gonna be for the employees with a 100% bar and 19 0% bars too (that we could probably hide, but still). If anything, those articles convinced me that pie charts are useful. Evil with small percentages, but still useful.

Comment: Btw, I managed to get something working based on switching to a *pie of pie chart* when there are more than 2 percentages under 10%. The visual is nearly the same for all employees, it's easy to compare, and it works. Both IT and non-IT guys are happy right now (even those with a math degree).

Comment: would you mind sharing the solution with others? kind of an interesting case here.. ( :